# Problems when removing `monodevelop`

Tags: 11.10, uninstall

When I tried to remove `monodevelop`, I got these errors:

```
root@So-so:~# sudo apt-get autoremove monodevelop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package monodevelop is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up monodoc-browser (2.10-1) ...
generating monodoc index...
grep: /etc/gre.d/*.conf: No such file or directory

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
dpkg: error processing monodoc-browser (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 monodoc-browser
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Try typing `sudo apt-get purge monodoc-browser` first

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using an invalid command to remove one package.  To remove the monodevelop package, you should use `apt-get remove monodevelop`.

Secondly, you should attempt to purge monodoc-browser, which is trying to finish installing itself.  Try using `apt-get remove --purge monodoc-browser`.